# Magento2: Reference 'copyright' design config field in email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates, copyright

Is it possible to reference the copyright field found in design configuration within the footer section? I've checked here https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/variables-reference.html with no luck. I would ultimately like to add it to my email footer.

Thank you, 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The copyright footer variable which you specified is currently not available in email variables. However You can add your own custom variable refer the below link.
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/variables-custom.html

I tried to add it in my system as shown in the below screenshots.

https://prnt.sc/ph9v22

https://prnt.sc/ph9vcq

Comment: Ah that makes sense! Thank you so much for this.

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as accepted if your problem is resolved

Comment: Ive tried! Still trying to build my reputation. As soon as I can figure out how to get passed the 15 reputation points I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you again!